# Unable to tap same listview item twice xamarin

Tags: xamarin

In xamarin list view using SelectedItem property, I cannot able to access same listview item twice.
1.tap an item in a list.it navigates to other back.
2.come back to the previous page and tap the same item in the list it is navigating to other page.

```
  <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding UIUnionListWrapper}"
            **SelectedItem="{Binding DeviceSession, Mode=TwoWay}">**
  internal DeviceSession _deviceSession;

    public DeviceSession DeviceSession
    {
        get { return _deviceSession; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _deviceSession, value);
            HandleItemSelectedAsync(); //navigating to other page
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you navigate back to your previous page where the list is, you have to set properties to all your items of isSelected to false. Otherwise listview retain that selection(since object hasnt been disposed yet).

Comment: i will know the root cause.Could you please share code snippet to do this or could you provide me more detail about isSelected property.

Comment: somebody please provide solution

Comment: In your HandleItemSelectedAsync set DeviceSession = null after navigating

Comment: I tried your solution already when you Set DeviSession=null it is navigating multiple times. Because of reassigning the value as null.

Comment: somebody please provide solution

Comment: Don't rely on binding for actions. Use ItemTapped Event for capturing the tap event, selected item will come as an argument, navigate to next page.

Comment: I'm using MVVM pattern so  I cannot use item tapped event

Comment: can someone provide me solution

Answer (score 0):

This code work as expected:`if (SelectedItem != null){await PushModelPage(newSessionListPage(SelectedItem, Navigation));SelectedItem = null;}`